# Circuit to connect/disconnect a battery from circuit input, controlled by the MCU, self-power-off

Tags: power, batteries, mosfet, switches, lithium-ion

Here is my current idea, but I'm wanting something better. Because in my circuit it is missing a way to discharge the capacitor C1 whenever the battery is disconnected from the circuit input. I have used a high-side switch with P-mosfet but it can be used low-side switch instead.

[image]

- The baterry will not be connected to circuit input (VIN) constantly, it can be connected/disconnected to/from the circuit input.
- When the battery be connected to VIN/circuit, I want VOUT to be connected to VIN initially, then the MCU will turn on and will imediatelly put one digital output to level '1' to guarantee that VOUT stay connected to VIN. Then the MCU will do its job (processing) in some seconds and after finished, the MCU will put the same digital output to '0' in order VOUT disconnects from VIN in order there will be only a few microAmps of consumption from the battery. If the battery be disconnected from the circuit and connected again, the process above should repeat.
- That is, if the MCU can do its job/processing in 10 seconds, but the battery was connected for a period of 60 seconds, there should be power consumption from the battery only for 10 seconds and not 60, because after 10 seconds the MCU will disable its own power (and power of the whole remaining circuit connected to Vout).

How to do such control with minimal parts? Is there specific ICs to do such job?

Consumption at Vout = 300mA MAX. After Vout comes a buck-boost switching regulator that will generate an stable 3.3V rail from the Li-Ion battery voltage range.

Regards.

**EDIT (1):**

- At VOUT there is connected a buck-boost switching regulator TPS63001, which has fixed 3.3V output voltage. Page 1 of its datasheet shows "Device Quiescent Current less than 50 μA".
- VIH of EN pin = 1.2V minimum. If I do control EN pin from the MCU, how would look the circuit? I will need a capacitor anyway, correct? Not just a pull-up.

Datasheet link: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps63001.pdf

[image]

**EDIT (2):**

Checking again the datasheet of TPS63001, it shows that the "Shutdown current" is 1uA at maximum.

[image]

**EDIT (3):**

I have decided that I will control the EN pin of TPS63001 with the MCU and by using passive components. Below is my circuit proposal to control the EN pin:

- Consumption of resistors when VBAT = 3.7V:
- I = 3.7V / 100K+3300K
- I(uA) = 3.7/3400 * 1000
- I(uA) = 1.088uA
- T = 0.1uF * 3300K
- T = (0.1*10^-6) * (3300*10^3)
- T = 0.33s
- 3T = 1s

I think there should be no considerable delay between EN be recognized as level 1 and the 3.3V output rail of TPS63001 be stable and the MCU powered on. The first thing the MCU will do is to place the digital output to level 1.

[image]

Comment: If the MCU is still active, a brief '1' on that I/O pin will discharge C1.

Comment: After the MCU put the output to level 0, it will be powered-off, because its power comes from VOUT, which will be deactivated

Comment: My approach would be to use a switching regulator with an **enable** input and a **low quiescent current** then the MCU can just directly control the switched regulator.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Check my edited topic

Comment: Consider that EN have a pull-up. EN will be 1 on start-up. But when it is the moment to put EN to 0, the MCU can't mantain a level 0 on EN pin, because it will loss its power after this, then the EN pin would be released from GND.

Comment: 50uA of power consumption is OK, but the circuit is not finished. Also, checking the datasheet again, the Shutdown current of that IC is 1uA MAX.

Comment: To me it looks like R5 (100 ohm) and C10 (1uF) are mainly needed for the VINA pin (Supply voltage for control stage), the values of R5 and C10 look to me like "supply filtering". I think you can just connect the EN input directly to the MCU output and keep the rest as shown above. I would add a **pull down** resistor (100 kohm) on the EN pin so that when the MCU hasn't initialized the output yet, the regulator will be off.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Yes, R5 and C10 form a noise filter for VINA (which is the supply voltage for control stage). Observe this: If I connect EN to a pin o MCU and place a pull-down resistor on it, the power supply will not start. Because, when the external battery be connected to VIN, EN will be low level due to the pull-down and the output of the MCU will be tri-state because it is not supplied yet. So, this way, the power supply will not even start.

Comment: *the power supply will not even start* Correct, you have to explicitly enable the power supply from the MCU before it will do **anything**. I'm assuming that's actually what you want as it prevents the situation where the switched converter is already on when the MCU isn't started up yet. Then anything can happen. Best avoid that.

Comment: A BJT, MOSFET, a few diodes, and some passives are all that's needed.

Comment: Yes, but what should be the minimal circuit?